# get name of select component in antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, antd

I can't get name of select component in antd to use handleInputChange function in onchange so i try to the setState in onchange and add to object

## UPDATED

```js
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
      const value = e.target.value;
      setNewCommodityAndService({ ...newCommodityAndService, [name]: value });
    }
  }; 

<Form.Item label="service">
    <Select
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      fieldNames="goods_group_id"
      placeholder="select"
      id="test"
    >
      {allCommodityAndServicesGroup?.map((commodityAndService) => {
        return (
          <Option value={commodityAndService.id}>{commodityAndService.name}</Option>
        )
      })
      }
    </Select>
   </Form.Item>
```

Comment: change `onChange={handleInputChange()}` to `onChange={handleInputChange}`

Comment: It's not clear what isn't working in your code. Is the value you get in `e.target.name` not the expected one?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the onChange prop wrongly. you are calling it in the props instead you need to just set the prop.

```
 <Select
  onChange={handleInputChange}
  fieldNames="goods_group_id"
  placeholder="select"
  id="test"
>
```

Comment: I reviewed code and fixed my mistake